React Native (Android) app gets stuck on white screen on release build with minifyEnabled true
I'm an Android developer who's currently working on a React Native project. I've been encountering an issue where my app gets stuck on a white screen specifically when building the release version with minifyEnabled true in the build.gradle file. Debugging works perfectly fine, and even when minifyEnabled is false for release builds, the app functions without any issues.
Here's a list of all the dependencies from my package.json file
  "dependencies": {
    "@int/email-view": "^1.1.1-133-mr6",
    "@int/essence-assist": "^1.0.4-30",
    "@int/ial-hermes": "0.1.44-718",
    "@int/infra-hermes": "3.10.20-79",
    "@int/react-native-from-main-proxy": "4.0.4",
    "@int/rn-native-utils": "0.1.42",
    "@int/s3-react-native-uploader": "^2.0.37-12",
    "@mui/base": "5.0.0-beta.40",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.14",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.14",
    "@mui/system": "^5.15.14",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.2",
    "@op-engineering/op-sqlite": "^2.0.22",
    "@protontech/jsmimeparser": "^3.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "19.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "19.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^19.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.16",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.14",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.22",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.6.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-bold": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-character-count": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-color": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-document": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-dropcursor": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-highlight": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-image": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-italic": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-link": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-list-item": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-mention": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-paragraph": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-table": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-table-cell": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-table-header": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-table-row": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-text": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-text-align": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-text-style": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-typography": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/extension-underline": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/pm": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/react": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/starter-kit": "^2.2.4",
    "@tiptap/suggestion": "^2.2.4",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "chroma-js": "^2.4.2",
    "i18next": "^23.10.0",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.7",
    "jwt-decode": "4.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "querystring": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^14.0.5",
    "react-native": "0.73.5",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-app-auth": "7.1.3",
    "react-native-background-timer": "2.4.1",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.8",
    "react-native-change-icon": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-color-palette": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-config": "1.5.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.13.1",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "8.6.3",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native-localize": "^3.0.6",
    "react-native-mime-types": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-mmkv": "2.12.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.3",
    "react-native-pell-rich-editor": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-performance-stats": "^0.2.3",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^5.1.8",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.8.0",
    "react-native-release-profiler": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-share": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.10",
    "react-native-web-webview": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  }

I suspect that the issue might be related to the ProGuard configuration. However, despite resolving some errors that were logged during the build process, the problem persists. Could someone please advise on what specific configurations I should include in my ProGuard file to address this issue?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
